# MVC partial view not staying on tesame page after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I'm currently working on a website in MVC, And i'm experiencing some problems

**What I would like to achieve:**

When a item is selected in the DropDownListFor it excecutes the form.Submit and goes to the RecipeController post "AddIngredient", in this HttpPost I add the logic to insert the ingredient into the SelectedIngredients list. This list will then be used to bind to the ListboxFor afterwards.

**What problem I am encountering:**

When clicking on a item in the DropDownListFor It successfully submits the form and goes to the HttpPost, the problem is after excecuting the post it goes to the /Recipe/AddIngredient/ and does not stay on the submit view

My code:

Submit.cshtml:

```
<div class="submit-recipe-form">
<div class="add-ingredient">
@Html.Partial("_AddIngredient");
</div>
```

_AddIngredient.cshtml (Partial view):

```
@model Recepten.Models.IngredientSelectModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddIngredient", "Recipe", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "add-ingredient", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ingredients, "Add Ingredient")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIngredient, Model.Ingredients, new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

RecipeController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddIngredient(IngredientSelectModel ing)
{
    //Logic
    return PartialView(ing);
}
```

IngredientSelectModel:

```
    public class IngredientSelectModel
    {
    public RecipeModel Recipe { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public int SelectedIngredient { get; set; }

    public string addIngredient { get; set; }

    public List<int> SelectedIngredients { get; set; }

    public IngredientSelectModel()
    {
        SelectedIngredients = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

I have the package jquery unobtrusive ajax installed and correctly listed in my bundle, I expect i'm missing something with the view in the HttpPost but not sure what exactly.

Thank you for your time!

EDIT:

Submit.cshtml
http://pastebin.com/yS8etDK5

Comment: If its displaying the partial instead or staying on the same page, it means `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not loaded in the view (or you have something invalid such as nested forms)

Comment: Have you tried to delete "@section Scripts {@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}" part in your partial view? Maybe this part caused to error.

Comment: http://imgur.com/qLraBOV as shown in the picture jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js seems to be loaded in the view, I have also tried removing @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") and assigning it in my submit view instead but that did not work. I will check and see if I have any nested forms

Comment: Is `jquery-{version}.js` also included before `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`?

Comment: yes, that is rendered in my _layout.cshtml page with @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") on the submit recipe page it shows src="/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" aswell

Comment: I have uploaded my full submit view on pastebin and added it to my OP to make sure i'm not missing out any nested forms, in my _layout.cshtml i'm never calling any form either

Comment: The pastebin code shows lots of form controls (`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Recipe.Title)`, `@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Recipe.Description)` etc). What is the point of those if you do not have a form in that view? Something does not make sense with what you have shown

Comment: I had a @using (Html.Beginform()){} for those but removed it for testing purposes regarding the partial view

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by replacing `@onchange = "this.form.submit();"` to `@onchange = "$(this).parents('form').submit();"`